# html - Create a video using HTML, CSS & CSS animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, css-animations

Let's say I have figured out the interface of a video editor in plain HTML5. I have all the necessary tools I need for the user to be able to create a video - except rendering it to a MP4 or MOV or whatever.

I also want to create the video using HTML, CSS & CSS animations, as then it would be easier. There is NO JavaScript framework of any sorts which is changing the HTML that will be used to make a video.

So, is there a program (**preferably** server-side) which can convert Styled HTML and CSS animations/transitions into an actual video that can, say for example, be uploaded to YouTube?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for: https://www.remotion.dev

Essentially, it is a ReactJS framework that uses SVG and WebGL to create complex motion graphics, which can include videos and images.

(I have no relation to the framework or its developers)

Comment: Wow. Thanks! This was just what I wanted. I was learning ReactJS, and with this, I think a good project might be a video editor.