Is it possible to export a Chart.js graph with animation?
I was wondering if there's a way to export my Chart.js animation. I created a statistics website and added a "delay" animation to the bar graph. You can see an example here: https://scrapifier.com/no_rbex .
I'd love to download this graph as a video, but from what I've found online, it seems like there isn't a straightforward method to do so.
Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how I might achieve it?
Thanks a lot for any help!
Here is the graph code if it helps in any way:
const ctx2 = document.getElementById('followerGrowthChart').getContext('2d');
const visibleBarsCount = Math.min(formattedTimestamps.length, 30); // Calculate the number of visible bars (up to 30 or less)
const startIndex = formattedTimestamps.length - visibleBarsCount; // Calculate the start index based on the number of visible bars
const followerGrowthChart = new Chart(ctx2, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: formattedTimestamps,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Total Follower Gain',
            data: barData, // Use modified data with minimum height for zero values
            backgroundColor: backgroundColors, // Array of colors
            borderColor: backgroundColors, // Match border color with background color

            pointRadius: 5,
            fill: true, // Ensure bars are filled
        }],
    },
    options: {
        animation: {
            onComplete: () => {
                delayed = true;
            },
            delay: (context) => {
                let delay = 0;
                if (context.type === 'data' && context.mode === 'default' && !delayed) {
                    // Adjust delay calculation based on the number of visible bars
                    delay = (context.dataIndex - startIndex) * 300 + context.datasetIndex * 100;
                }
                return delay;
            },
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                grid: {
                    color: 'rgba(185, 187, 190, 0.1)'
                },
                ticks: {
                    precision: 0
                }
            },
            x: {
                grid: {
                    color: 'rgba(185, 187, 190, 0.1)'
                },
                max: formattedTimestamps[formattedTimestamps.length - 1], // Last timestamp
                min: formattedTimestamps[startIndex] // Use the start index to set the minimum timestamp
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
    },
});

Thank you again!
Try using chatGPT to know if there is a way to do it and searched online for any video.

What about a screen capture tool?

@Pointy i would love to add an "Export as video" button, not using a software to capture my screen and crop it.. :(

FYI if you tried to add a link, it didn't work. You may want to [edit] your question

Thanks. I honestly don't see how you'd be able to do this except via some sort of screen-capture mechanism, because chartJS just gives code to the browser about what animation to run, and exactly how that appears, how fast it runs, when it finishes etc, is all in the hands of the capability of the browser, the size of the viewport etc. My sense is you might be able to make some progress via the JS screen capture API, but I haven't used it myself so YMMV

You might want to look at https://www.remotion.dev/, from this Q+A: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66717942/95033. Not Chart.js specific, never used it myself, but it sounds like what you're looking for.
